# Pasting features into a feature class doesn't honour subtypes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, versioning, subtype

I'm encountering an issue where features that I'm copying from a feature class in a file geodatabase are all going to a single subtype when I paste them in the destination feature class in an enterprise geodatabase (Versioned). Subtypes are identical in both feature classes. The paste operation is not honouring the subtype of the original data.

I'm using ArcGIS 10.3.1.

My workflow:

1. Start an edit session on a version of an enterprise geodatabase.
2. Select 15 features in a file geodatabase feature class called **SewerMaintenanceHoles**.
3. Copy these features and paste them into the corresponding feature class in the enterprise geodatabase. It is also called **SewerMaintenanceHoles**.
4. Because the destination feature class contains a subtype (which is identical to the source feature class subtype), I get the following option when I paste:
   [image]

You can see in the attribute table the source values are shown and there are 3 different possible values (Maintenance Hole, Maintenance Shaft and TEP). I don't want to paste all the features into a specific subtype. I want the paste to honour the original values in the source feature class. So, I chose the top level (Sewer_Maintenance_Holes). I thought that would paste the features into their corresponding subtype. What is happening instead is that all features are pasting to the default subtype which is Maintenance Hole.

[image]

Note, USE is an alias for the Subtype field. But, they're all coming in as Maintenance Hole.

[image]

How can I get the original subtype values to come through to the destination feature class?

Answer (score 1):

Tested that pasting does not respect the subtypes on 10.5.1. Tested on 10.3.1 and the results are the same; the values are being inserted into a default subtype. I've reported this to the Tech Support; there is a bug registered `BUG-000111885: Pasting the features between the feature classes does not respect subtype`. Your only option is to use the GP tool. Please note that this behavior can be observed on any type of geodatabase (file to file or file to enterprise).

As a workaround, you could just use the Append GP tool (without specifying a particular subtype); both on 10.3.1 and 10.5.1 this also loads features into their respective subtypes (respecting the selection so you can load only the features you need).

Comment: I don't think this will work as I'm writing to a version.

Comment: Do you know that you can establish a connection to a particular version before writing features? The GP tool `Change version` does that. http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/changeversion.htm Either manually or with the help of `arcpy`.

Comment: @Fezter, I've tried to do the copy/paste in Pro 2.1 and it seems to be working fine http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/editing/copy-and-paste-using-the-clipboard.htm

Comment: Thanks Alex. Unfortunately the client is using 10.3.1 for now. But that's good to know.